# in c++11, is it necessary to provide rvalue overrides for functions move-assigning large objects?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

**When providing a function that copies a large object, do I need to provide an explicit override accepting an rvalue to benefit from move assignment?**

Most of the discussion of when to explicitly provide rvalue overrides is focused on constructors and assignment operators, or return values. But I can't quite figure out how it applies to copying/move-assigning large objects.

consider:

```
struct A{
  //my owned data, any large object that implements move assignment
  std::vector<std::string> myvec;

  //pre-c++11, this would assign by copy
  void Set(const std::vector<std::string>& vec){ myvec = vec; }

  //c++11, explicitly move assign
  void Set(std::vector<std::string>&& vec){ myvec = std::move(vec); }
};

A a;
a.Set(std::vector<std::string>({"hello","world"});
```

If I call `Set` with an lvalue, the first version of the method (`const T&` will be called, and the assignment will be done by copy.  As it is written, the call at the bottom of the snippet will call the second version of `Set` (`T&&`) because the temporary object is an rvalue.

I read somewhere (can't find the reference now) that `const T&` can bind to rvalues.  If that's the case, and my `T` implements a move-assign operator (as `std::vector` does), will the first version allow efficient move-assignment of rvalues, making the `T&&` override unnecessary?

Comment: For some applications, I've seen just providing the equivalent of `void Set(std::vector<string> vec){ myvec = std::move(vec); }`. It costs an extra move in all cases but you get away with just one function without having to repeat yourself.

Comment: Yes, `const T&` can bind to rvalues. But the `T` object is marked as **`const`**, so can't be moved from.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Doesn't it cost a copy + move? Copy as the object is passed into the function body, followed by move assignment?  I guess for temporaries, the copy is elided, but not for true lvalues...?

Comment: @thegreatemu I was missing an "extra" in there. It costs and *extra* move. For lvalues you get a copy plus a move, for rvalues you get two moves.

Comment: Do note that if T in the accepted answer is something that could be constructed by a std::initializer_list, like your vector, this won't allow you to use a list in the call. set_a({1,2,3}) would hae to become set_a(A{1,2,3}) since braced-init-list's don't have a type.  You would still need to add a `Set(std::initializer_list<std::string>)` overload to get the same behavior as you current code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It can be pretty costly by requiring allocations where none were required. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554916/1896169